# create array of object using interface in angular

Tags: angular

I would like to initialize an array with one object inside.

Then, using a function I'd like to be able to push one empty object on it on even later delete one object.

So I have create an interface with the value that are in my object ;

```
export class Session {
    constructor(
      public genre: string,
      public ordre_interface: number,
      public nb_serie: number
  
    ) {}

    myObject = {} as Session;

}
```

Then in my main .ts file, I import this interface and initialize my array.

```
import {Session} from './session.model';

session = [] as Array<Session>;
```

and I add a function to push a new object inside the array.

```
addObject() {

    let ses = new Session();
    this.session.push(ses);
}
```

But first, when I initialize my array session, I like to have one empty object inside like that of I got an empty array [] :

```
session = [
{
genre: '',
ordre_interface: null,
nb_serie: null,
}
];
```

And second, inside my function, my code gives me error on line let ses = new Session() :

```
 Expected 3 arguments, but got 0
```

I'd like it to create a new object and put it inside the array like that :

```
session = [
{
genre: '',
ordre_interface: null,
nb_serie: null,
},
{
genre: '',
ordre_interface: null,
nb_serie: null,
}
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
export class Session {
    public genre?: string;
    public ordre_interface?: number;
    public nb_serie?: number;
    
    constructor() {}
}
```

This way you can create a new object with empty data.